# How to include checkbox in the title of dojo content pane present in AccordionContainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried some code similar to this:

```
<div id="markupAccordion" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props='style:"width: 400px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden"'>     
    <div id="pane11" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:" i need some text boxes or buttons here", iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",selected:true'>
        <p>
            Some Text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the checkbox to the title using direct html::

```
 <div id="pane12" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"dbox1\" checked> <label for=\"dbox1\">Want</label>", iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",selected:true'>
```

If you want the checkbox to be a widget, its a litter tougher since the title does not get parsed.  You can create the checkbox programmatically, then add it to the title.  The title id will always be the _button_title

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/registry", "dojo/dom-construct"], function (CheckBox, reg, dom) {
    var box1 = new CheckBox({
        id: "pbox1",
        checked: true,
    });
    dom.place(box1.domNode, "pane11_button_title", "first");
    box1.startup();

});
```

jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/D7rju/#base